# Lebesgue norm over a ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball centred at $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of radius $r>0$.

Let $r_0$ be a fixed point.

Is the following proposition true?

"$[\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n~~~ \|f\|_{L^p(B(x,r_0))}=0]\Rightarrow \|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}=0$"

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, and for a very simple reason. Let $\{q_k\}$ be an enumeration of the rational points in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\mathbb R^n \subset \cup_k B(q_k,r_0)$, and in particular $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^p \, dx \le \sum_k \int_{B(q_k,r_0)} |f|^p \, dx = 0.$$